# npm install fails with EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, permissions

I am trying to install Node.js on a Debian 9 (Stretch) box. Initially I run the following commands as root:

```
curl -Lo node.tar.xz https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.0/node-v10.15.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
echo "4ee8503c1133797777880ebf75dcf6ae3f9b894c66fd2d5da507e407064c13b5 node.tar.xz" | sha256sum -c -
tar xJf node.tar.xz
cp -a node-v10.15.0-linux-x64/. /usr/local/
```

Next I run `npm install`, from the source dir of the project I am trying to build, with a regular user account, and get the following error:

```
> git-validate@2.2.2 install /blah/node_modules/git-validate
> node bin/install

fs.js:115
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/blah/.git/hooks/pre-commit'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1190:35)
    at Object.exports.installHooks (/blah/node_modules/git-validate/lib/utils.js:248:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/blah/node_modules/git-validate/bin/install.js:3:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! git-validate@2.2.2 install: `node bin/install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the git-validate@2.2.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-20T19_55_48_025Z-debug.log
```

The source dir is a git repo cloned under the same user account which is now running `npm install`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with sudo npm install?

Comment: @vitomadio I tried and this worked, but I consider that a workaround, not a solution. Also that still doesn’t explain why it would fail on a folder in the user’s home dir, in a git repo cloned with that same user account. There shouldn’t be anything the user would not have access to…

Comment: Just another thought: the environment I run this in is set up to remove the `sudo` package after the list of sudo commands have run. Does `npm install` invoke `sudo` at any point? That would explain the behavior…

Comment: Yes, it is, here is a link that could help you workarount this issue https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally